# Signtool SignerSign() Error (-1073700864/0xc000a000)

Tags: signtool

where can i find the meaning of this error for the program SignTool.exe?

```
"Error: SignerSign() failed." (-1073700864/0xc000a000)
```

I have been getting this error randomly for a few days when calling the command

```
signtool.exe sign /debug /a /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 MyDll.dll
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes i did. not conclusive.

Comment: Seems to be related to random errors while contacting the RFC 3161 time stamp server.

Comment: When ended up changing server. Switched to http://timestamp.digicert.com.
Fixed our problem.

Comment: Just had a customer using this exact same timestamp server for months suddenly have this problem today.  They are now pointed to timestamp.digicert.com.

Comment: Yup, me too. Thanks. Should add a proper answer and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

Same issue occurred using a godaddy code singing certificate to sign a msi installer.

`/tr` specifies the URL of the RFC 3161 time stamp server.

Changing the url from http://tsa.starfieldtech.com to http://timestamp.digicert.com solves the problem.

`signtool.exe sign /debug /a /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td SHA256 MyDll.dll`

Answer (score 2):

Even I was facing same problem during jenkins build. The problem got resolved by adding seconds delay before you sign the next binary.

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 16 > nul

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for the past two days with Sectigo (Comodo CA) where all my post build signings kept randomly failing.  Has been fine for two years and interestingly exactly 1-year to the day before the certificate expires these errors start happening. It seems as though it would work with a single build but for multiple builds it would randomly complain about one of them and not always the same.

changing my post build event from:

```
signtool.exe sign /f "$(ProjectDir)my-cert.pfx" /p mypassword /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll"
```

to:

```
signtool.exe sign /f "$(ProjectDir)my-cert.pfx" /p mypassword /t http://timestamp.digicert.com "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll"
```

solved the problem.